# Why do I get this kind of error "System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Text' on type 'String' not found.'" in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to insert data to MySql using vb.net. When I try to insert I've got the error. Please Help me.

```
Private Sub addEmp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addEmp.Click

    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
   "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=vbdb"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Dim birthDate As String = bDay.Value.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")
    Dim dateHired As String = dHired.Value.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd")

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "insert into vbdb.employee_info (Last_Name, First_Name, Middle_Name, Gender, Birthdate, Address, Contact, Position, Emp_Type, Email, Date_Hired) values ('" & firstName.Text & "','" & lastName.Text & "','" & middleName.Text & "','" & gender.Text & "','" & birthDate & "','" & gender.Text & "','" & address.Text & "','" & contact.Text & "','" & position.SelectedItem.Text & "','" & type.SelectedItem.Text & "','" & email.Text & "','" & dateHired & "')"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader

        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Learn how to use parameters and do not use strings to store datetime values

Comment: Never glue strings together to make SQL, and dont store dates as text 
 if `bDay` and  `dHired` are DateTimePickers store the `Value` dont convert to string.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `position.SelectedItem.Text`.  Presumably `position` is a `ComboBox` or `ListBox` and you have bound it to some list.  Presumably the property or column that you have specified via the `ValueMember` contains `Strings`.  That means that `position.SelectedItem` is a `String` and you are trying to access a `Text` member that doesn't exist.

For one thing, you should turn `Option Strict On`.  That code wouldn't even compile then.  That would mean that, if `position.SelectedItem` is a `String`, you would have to cast it as that type, probably using `CStr`.  If it wasn't already obvious that you already had the `String` you needed, the compiler would tell you without your having to run the project that type `String` had no `Text` property.